# How to add a static block on all pages on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, static-block, cms-pages

I want to add a static block on the left side of all pages.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: check my answer here , adding block ..you can select the container where to display https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186986/magento-2-custom-theme-which-files-to-edit-in-order-to-customize-home-page-c/187029#187029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, override the 2columns-left.xml in your theme module and define every page's column layout as 2column-left from XML and cms pages. Than put following code in your 2columns-left.xml file

```
<referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
    <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
       <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="blockname">
         <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cmsblock-identifier</argument>
         </arguments>
       </block>
    </container>
    <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
        <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Above code will display your static block in the left side of your every 2columns-left style page.

The code to add cms block is:

```
       <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="blockname">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cmsblock-identifier</argument>
            </arguments>
       </block>
```

Comment: My pleasure.. :) @AlinLupoiu

Answer (score 6):

**If you want to call static block in page in magento 2**

Try this below code :

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

**If you want to call in phtml file :**

Try this below code :

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

**Your xml file code should be :**

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="yourblockid">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">yourblockid</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**At Last if you want to call phtml with your block in cms page :**

Try this below code :

```
{{block class="Magento\Modulename\Block\Blockname" template="Magento_Modulename::templatefilename.phtml"}}
```

Refer this link for more details - https://chetansanghani.wordpress.com/2015/11/20/magento2-display-static-block-in-phtml-file-cms-page/

Comment: You can edit column files.