# How to customize the magento header

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, customize

I am very new to Magento and did not know much about this so pardon my mistakes. Actually, I have deployed it on the local server and it is running fine. I want to customize this like I want to change the heading logo colors. I have worked on `CodeIgniter` but that was simple, having HTML. How can I customize it? It will be a great help.

**P.s** The default theme is I think LUMA.

**What I have tried**: I have tried from going to the admin panel but the only option was the logo. I have tried the code but I was not able to locate the file where I can change these things.

Comment: did you get the solution for this ?

Comment: @ManojDeswal kind off but not completely. actually this question was very broad i think and should be split to the parts in asking the question.

Comment: yes ask multiple question , not much in a single question ...so post your specific requirement so you will get better solution

Comment: yeah my fault i should have asked specific problems. Problem was i did not know a thing in magento.

Comment: you want to changes styles , right ? see here how to change custom styles https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187029/54588

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to do exactly ?

For logo it's an image, so you can't just change the color, in back end you can change the logo directly in (but you already know this, I resume for new dev) :

> **Content** > **Design** > **Configuration**

Select first line "**Global**" to apply modification on all stores.

Under sub menu **Header** (i think, I use french install) you can change logo.

Comment: i mean to say how can i change the colours of header bar? or all the styling?

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be a comment, rather than an answer, but I don't have the reputation to post a comment.

Better to Create Custom CSS file on your own [How to add a custom CSS file in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2)

Hope this helps.