# Display a custom navigation block instead of the default one

Tags: magento-2.1.7, navigation

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and  I have
created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

In the back-end, I have created a **block** with a custom, hard-coded, navigation like:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

By default, Magento displays links to the **product categories** in the **top menu**:

`<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>`

How do I, instead, display my **custom links block**?

Comment: let me know if any problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To show your Custom Block Navigation , you simply need to create a widget**

- Go to `admin > content > widgets > add widget`
- Select type as **CMS static Block** and choose your theme whichever you are using
- Fill all the details  ( Title / Assign to Store Views / Sort Order to **"0"**
- Add layout update > **Display** on all pages / **Container**: After page header
- Widget options > Select your block

**Keep your cache disabled or clean/flush your cache**

You can remove your default navigation by below code in your custom `Magento_Theme` module, if required.

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />
```

> Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml

I hope this will help you out and others as well

Comment: I did all the above and the default navigation is displayed as well.
Can I alternatively make changes in defaul.xml considering that `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
     <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-" remove="true"/>
    </block>`?

Comment: No need to do any coding in XML just simple create widget , see working example here https://www.smartparcelbox.com/ .. navigation and each block on homepage displayed via widget and blocks

Comment: first , display your static block on front end using widget ... then we will remove default menu.... flush your cache or check in different browser , if you created widget in above mentioned way then it should display

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187029/54588 ,  displayed ?

Comment: I can not use `<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />` because I need to display the categories on the page still, but in the sidebar. What alternative do I have?

Comment: This will remove only from top bar not from sidebar

Comment: It removes both as I have: `<referenceContainer name="main">
   <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.leftnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
   <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
  </referenceContainer>`

Comment: So how you are hiding default top nav as you are using via static block

Comment: I have **edited**  the question.

Comment: can be solved , using a simple CSS tweaks if you could share the WEB URL then I can tell you the exact code...... or you can move your top menu to left in desired container via xml

Comment: I know it can easily be solved with CSS and I know how. But don't we have e more "elegant" solution?

Comment: do not place in left side .... remove whatever you done for that .....after that move "catalog.topnav"   to left sidebar

Comment: Whai I did is: `<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.leftnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>` but if I remove `<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml"/>
    </block>` the left navigation disappears too.